# Social Tables API: Size limit for Event Name field

Tags: social-tables

What is the size limit for the 'name' field when creating an event with the Layout Automation Social Tables API endpoint?

https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Layout_Automation/post_4_0_layout_automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` field is automatically truncated to 255 characters, but this limit will not result in an error at request time.